# JPA select with two conditions

Tags: java, jpa, criteriabuilder

Help me please add two conditions for JPA.

I have the entity Subject *(some subject of a teacher – math, biology, programming and so one).*
Subject has a field: boolean deleted.

```
@Entity
public class Subject {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean deleted;
```

I have the second entity Teacher. It has `Set<Subject> subjects` – subjects which are attached to the teacher.

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
public class Teacher extends Person {
    private boolean deleted;
    Set<Subject> linkedSubjects;
}
```

So I need to get list of subjects which are not yet attached to the teacher AND these subjects should not be deleted.

I can do this separately – get not attached or get not deleted. But how get both of them?

```
    public List<Subject> findSubjectNotInList(List<Subject> teacherSubjects) { // teacherSubjects - List subjects which still attached to a teacher
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Subject> query = cb.createQuery(Subject.class);
        Root<Subject> root = query.from(Subject.class);
     // Get all not attached:
     // query.select(root).where(root.in(teacherSubjects).not());           

     // Get all not deleted         
        query.select(root).where(cb.isFalse(root.get(Subject_.DELETED))); 

        List<Subject> subjects = em.createQuery(query).getResultList(); 
        return subjects;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно создавать предикаты для условия WHERE, а затем их объединять. Делать это можно так:

```
Predicate predicateForRedColor
  = criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("color"), "blue");
Predicate predicateForGradeB
  = criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("grade"), "B");
Predicate predicateForRedColorAndGradeB
  = criteriaBuilder.and(predicateForRedColor, predicateForGradeB);
```

Больше можно прочитать
[здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-and-or-criteria-predicates)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но нашлось более простое решение. Выложил ниже:

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
public List<Subject> findSubjectNotInList(List<Subject> teacherSubjects)
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Subject> query = cb.createQuery(Subject.class);
Root<Subject> root = query.from(Subject.class);
query.select(root)
    .where(cb.and(
        root.in(teacherSubjects).not(),
        cb.isFalse(root.get(Subject_.DELETED))));
List<Subject> subjects = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
return subjects;
```